# What does the branching factor mean in the time complexity of Breadth-First Search (BFS)

Tags: search, time-complexity, breadth-first-search

Can someone explain where my math is off here?

I am confused on the b - Branching Factor and how to calculate the worst-case scenario when running BFS. In a worst-case scenario BFS would have to hit every single node from the root node to the goal node giving the complexity of 1 (root node) + b (number of nodes at depth 1) + b^2 (number of nodes at depth 2) + ... + b^d = b^d.

Based on the following image does that mean the Time Complexity is has an upper bound of O(b^d) = O(2^4) = 16 nodes + 1 = 17 Nodes?

[image]
[Image Reference](https://www.javatpoint.com/ai-uninformed-search-algorithms)

Of course, if this was a complete binary tree with max nodes at depth of 4 there would be a total of 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 = 31 Nodes so the previous complexity does not make sense.

Thank You!

Comment: $O(.)$ does not give you the worst case in an exact sense, but in an asymptotic sense, indeed it can be off by any constant, so $O(b^2)$ might even be $1000000\cdot b^d$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Math is just fine. Its all about the definition of $\mathrm{O}(\cdot)$. Checkout the wiki page about [Big-O Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Basically, your function $T(b) = 1 + b + b^{2} + \cdots + b^{d}$ belongs to the class of functions $\mathrm{O}(b^{d})$ if its upper bound is at most $b^{d}$ **multiplied by some constant**.

Note that:
$$ T(d) = 1 + b + b^{2} + \cdots + b^{d} \leq (d+1)b^{d}, $$
which means that $T(d) \in \mathrm{O}(b^{d})$.

You could also obviously say that $T(d) \in \mathrm{O}(b^{d+1})$. If you want to be more specific about the complexity class to which your function belongs, then you can use [Big-Theta Notation](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/big-big-theta-notation) instead.

Your function $T(b) = 1 + b + b^{2} + \cdots + b^{d}$ belongs to the class of functions $\mathrm{\Theta}(b^{d})$ if its upper bound is at most $b^{d}$ multiplied by some constant **and its lower bound is at least $b^{d}$ multiplied by some constant**.

You have:
\begin{align}
T(d) &= 1 + b + b^{2} + \cdots + b^{d} \leq (d+1)b^{d} \\
T(d) &= 1 + b + b^{2} + \cdots + b^{d} \geq b^{d},
\end{align}
which means that $T(d) \in \mathrm{\Theta}(b^{d})$.

**HOWEVER**, you can still say that $T(d) \in \Theta(b^{d+1})$....
\begin{align}
T(d) &= 1 + b + b^{2} + \cdots + b^{d} \leq b^{d+1} \\
T(d) &= 1 + b + b^{2} + \cdots + b^{d} \geq \frac{1}{b}b^{d+1}.
\end{align}

So, people mostly just say that the complexity class is "exponent of $b$", without thinking too much whether the power is $d$ or $d+1$.

Also this [youtube video](https://youtu.be/FUaY0N4qVPY?list=PLhMnuBfGeCDNgVzLPxF9o5UNKG1b-LFY9&t=2460) is highly recommended.